# Big O's Logarithmic example - find how many operations?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, logarithm

I'm trying  to understand a logarithmic order of the O(log(n)) notation.

My online course has the following example:

Imagine that we have a data set of 10 items. We run an algorithm on that data set, and it performs 10 operations.
If we  doubled the size of the data set to 20 items, approximately how many operations might now be required for the algorithm of the logarithmic order?

I have assumed that log(n) has a base 2. so log2(10)= 3.322.
however, the answer for this example is 15.

Can anybody explain how to arrive at this answer please?  thank you.

P.S. the answer goes on to explain that 'If the algorithm is of logarithmic order, then multiplying the size of the data set by a factor  multiplies the number of operations required by a square root of n' (i.e the number of operations required increases with the square root of the size of the data set is that correct?)

Comment: What’s your source for this claim? That doesn’t seem right to me.

Comment: Taking the log2 of 10 seems like a good first step towards finding a plausible characteristic formula for this algorithm. But why do you then multiply 10 by that 3.322? If it were 3.322 operations per item, that would almost make sense. But if it were 3.322 operations per item, then it would be constant time, not logarithmic. So that can't be the right approach, can it?

Comment: it is from an online course, Computing in Python IV: Objects & Algorithms, on Edx. I assumed that I needed to multiply the initial 10 operations by some factor.

Answer (score 1):

This question is impossible to answer. There is not enough information.

Big O notation doesn't have to accurately reflect the function's behaviour for small numbers. So the fact that the time complexity is O(log n) says nothing about what we should expect for small inputs like 10 items or 20 items.

But even ignoring that, a logarithmically-scaling function is one where if you multiply the input by a constant factor (e.g. 2 in this question), then the output (i.e. number of operations) is increased by some constant amount. There is no possible way to determine the latter from just the information given in the question. It could be any positive number.

So if the question is exactly as you have written here, then the question is badly constructed. If there is a way to give feedback, consider doing so.

---

Edit: you've just added this quote to the question:

> If the algorithm is of logarithmic order, then multiplying the size of the data set by a factor multiplies the number of operations required by a square root of n

This is totally wrong. Whoever wrote this doesn't know what they're talking about. There is nothing else to say about it.

Comment: yes, the question was worded exactly like I wrote it here.. I thought that I needed to use 10x (square root of 2) = 14,  to get the answer close to 15.  however, I cant explain why. I have just left a feedback on this very question.

Comment: OK. so log2(1024) is 10, and log2( 1050000) is 20  and log2(32800) = 15. so, just by looking at the scale of these numbers,  there is no  way the number of operations can increase from 10 to 15, is there?  what would be your best guess?

Comment: There are infinitely many functions in O(log n) where f(10) = 10. There are infinitely many of those where f(20) = 15, and there are infinitely many where f(20) is whatever else you want. If you want to know where the course instructor got 15 from, you would have to ask them.

Comment: thank you.  it really is impossible to say where 15 came from in this multiple choice test.